# How to replace some xml tags in text

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

I have string = `Hello, <param value="username"/>!`.
I need to process it and replace all param-tags with certain variables.

1) s = `Hello, <param value="username"/>!`

2) processing

3) s = "Hello, Adam!"

I need help finding libraries to solve these kinds of problems.
Do you know such?

Answer (score 1):

The standard library has an [XML parser](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := `Hello, <param value="username"/>!`

    d := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(s))
    for {
        t, err := d.Token()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        switch t := t.(type) {
        case xml.CharData:
            fmt.Print(string(t))
        case xml.StartElement:
            fmt.Print("Adam")
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("")
}

// Output:
// Hello, Adam!
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple job for an XSLT stylesheet. Something like:

```
<xsl:template match="param">
  <xsl:value-of select=$supplied-params//param[@name=current()/@value]/@value"/>
</xsl:template>
```

where `$supplied-params` is an XML document containing the parameter values e.g.

```
<params>
  <param name="username" value="Adam"/>
</params>
```